# Any simple python code suggestions to add a constant to every individual number in a .txt

Tags: python, file, text, edit

so -----2-----3----5----2----3----- would become -----4-----5----7----4----5-----
if the constant was 2 and etc. for every individual line in the text file.

This would involve splitting recognising numbers in between strings and adding a constant to them e.g ---15--- becomes ---17--- not ---35---.

(basically getting a guitar tab and adding a constant to every fret number)

Thanks. Realised this started out vague and confusing so sorry about that.

lets say the file is:

-2--3--5---7--1/n-6---3--5-1---5

and im adding 2, it should become:

-4--5--7---9--3/n-8---5--7-3---7

Comment: If the file contains the text `--13--`, should the output be `--15--` or `--35--`?

Comment: can you tell us exactly what you want

Comment: What about `29` or `9`? Could you please clarify the basic idea about the rules the numbers are edited on?

Comment: output should be --15-- not --35--. all numbers edited are in the set of real integers.

Answer (score 1):

Change the filename to something relevant and this code will work. Anything below new_string needs to be change for what you need, eg writing to a file.

```
def addXToAllNum(int: delta, str: line):
    values = [x for x in s.split('-') if x.isdigit()]
    values = [str(int(x) + delta) for x in values]
    return '--'.join(values)

new_string = '' # change this section to save to new file
for line in open('tabfile.txt', 'r'):
    new_string += addXToAllNum(delta, line) + '\n'


## general principle
s = '-4--5--7---9--3 -8---5--7-3---7'
addXToAllNum(2, s) #6--7--9--11--10--7--9--5--9
```

Comment: on defining the function it gives the error of not knowing what delta is.

Comment: Try deleting the int: and str: in the arguments.

Comment: oh yeah. im dumb oops, thanks a lot this works perfectly.

Comment: is there a way to generalise this for the file containing other chars that arent  just '-' such as '|' and words and stuff?

Comment: I would probably use regular expressions at that point. You can modity the s.split('-' or '|' or '@') in this code to make it work, but I would just extract the numbers with Regular Expressions then recombine them. Look up the re module.

Answer (score 1):

This takes all numbers and increments by the `shift` regardless of the type of separating characters.

```
import re

shift = 2

numStr = "---1----9---15---"
print("Input: " + numStr)

resStr = ""
m = re.search("[0-9]+", numStr)
while (m):
  resStr += numStr[:m.start(0)]
  resStr += str(int(m.group(0)) + shift)
  numStr = numStr[m.end(0):]
  m = re.search("[0-9]+", numStr)
resStr += numStr

print("Result:" + resStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You Can use that to betwine every line in text file add  `-`

```
rt = ''
f = open('a.txt','r')
app = f.readlines()
for i in app:
    rt+=str(i)+'-'
print " ".join(rt.split())
```

Comment: That's not too helpful in what im trying to achieve sadly, the result isnt too helpful.

Comment: I tested it and it just reprinted it with some extra dashes inbetween lines

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

c = 2   # in this example, the increment constant value is 2

with open ('<your file path here>', 'r+') as file:
    new_content = re.sub (r'\d+', lambda m : str (int (m.group (0)) + c), file.read ())
    file.seek (0)
    file.write (new_content)
```